# How to set FormMethod.Get with Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have my form do a Get rather than a Post (It's a query field the user is submitting)

I know I can do it with

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Get) {%>
```

However, I would rather not have to specify the action/Controller and there doesn't seem to be an overload that takes FormMethod only.

This is MVC 1.0 (and without the futures)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such overload in the framework. However, if you send in action and controller as `null` the framework will do what you want. If you don't like that you can create that extension yourself:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, FormMethod method) {
    return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, method);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work? It calls `BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object routeValues)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<form method="get" action="<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller")%>" >`